# Lettrine + Stackengine: Bad placement of dropped capital

Tags: vertical-alignment, lettrine, stackengine

**Updated: No longer an issue with `lettrine` 2.01**

Weirdly, this has been working fine for me for months (if not years), however I've been able to boil down my issue to a MWE and it appears that including `stackengine` (whether it is used or not) causes the `lettrine` to be misplaced.

Rendering with stackengine commented out:
[image: stackengine commented out]

With stackengine included:
[image: stackengine included]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{paper}

%%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lettrine}

%%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\lettrine{J}{ohn Doe} was born in 1857 and lived until he was very old and moved around a lot. And so it was that blah blah blah.... Several years and words later this paragraph ends.

\end{document}
```

Comment: lettrine uses faulty code (`\global\setlength`) which doesn't work if the calc package is loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lettrine uses in various places \global\setlength which relies on a side effect that doesn't work with the calc package.

With some changes it works again:

```
\documentclass{paper}

%%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\makeatletter
\def\Lettrine@height{%
   \ifvoid\L@tbox
     \sbox{\L@tbox}{\LettrineTextFont{\LettrineSecondString}}%
   \fi
   \setlength{\L@target@ht}{\ht\L@tbox}%
   \@tempdima=\baselineskip
   \setlength{\L@target@dp}{\value{L@lines}\@tempdima}%
   \ifnum\value{L@lines}>1
     \addtolength{\L@target@dp}{-\@tempdima}%
   \else
     \addtolength{\L@target@ht}{\L@target@dp}%
     \setlength{\L@target@dp}{0pt}%
   \fi
   \setlength{\L@target@tht}{\L@target@ht}%
   \addtolength{\L@target@tht}{\L@target@dp}%
   \global\L@target@ht=\L@target@ht
   \global\L@target@dp\L@target@dp
   \global\L@target@tht\L@target@tht
   \setlength{\L@height}{\L@target@tht}%
   \addtolength{\L@height}{\L@oversize\L@target@tht}%
}
\makeatother
%%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\lettrine{J}{ohn Doe} was born in 1857 and lived until he was very old and moved around a lot. And so it was that blah blah blah.... Several years and words later this paragraph ends.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however this seems to completely disable any lraise setting I make -- `\lettrine[lraise=___]{J}{ohn Doe}`

Comment: Ah sorry, I overlooked the  `\L@target@tht` (with the t). I will add it.

Comment: lettrine is maintained, so you should notify the author.

Comment: Okay, will do..

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher: thanks for the patch, I'll issue a corrected version (2.01) of the lettrine package today.

Comment: @DanielFlipo Fine. Btw: I wouldn't  have expected a french to drop the c from my name, more the s ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, sorry for the typo :-(

Comment: Thank you for vindicating `stackengine`, LOL.  +1!

Comment: I have tested my documents with `lettrine` 2.01 and everything works. Thanks! :)